# Plugins for Character Rigging

Tags: after-effects, plugins

Are there any plugins or scripts that make it easy to create Character Rigging?

I just watched a video that shows something I've never seen in AE.

Is this something I can incorporate into the software?

Comment: Look up DUIK by rainbox studios. Free rigging tool that is pretty essential for character work. https://rainboxprod.coop/en/tools/duik/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this site there are some interesting scripts for you to use:

[AEScripts](http://aescripts.com/after-effects/automation/rigging/)